# jQuery - Change child iframe not whole page?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, find, createelement

I'm trying to get the child iframe and set it's source in my div called "myLittleModal"

```
function createModalElement( modalClassName ) {
return $('body').append("<div class=\""+ modalClassName + "\"><iframe></iframe></div>");
}


var modalElement = createModalElement( "myLittleModal" );
//alert(modalElement.text());           
modalElement.find('iframe').attr('src', "modal.html");
```

But it's actually changing the source of not only the iframe, but another iframe as well, which isn't a child of this perticular element at all. ??? WHY!?

I thought modalElement would be a handle to the particular element i created, by which i could manipulate it's specific child iframe (not needing a class as it's a child of the class i can style).

Upon looking in the source code console in chrome, i see that it's also changing the source of another iframe on the page, which is for testing purposes now, loading a live page. WHY???

This also happens if i use the children("iframe") function as well.

Please help

Comment: You have to do within a selector's context. you should mention where and how you are changing the iframe src attribute?

Comment: Does `modalElement` represent your `div` containing iframe or maybe `body` instead? Check it within console.

Comment: Yes the idea is that modalElement represents the div, and then I can traverse to find a child element which is the only one, an iframe. I want to access that iframe node in order to change it's source.

I know webenos code works, but can someone explain why mine is referencing the body and not the div I created?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `createModalElement` function with the following:

```
function createModalElement( modalClassName ) {
    $('body').append("<div class=\""+ modalClassName + "\"></div>");
    return $('.' + modalClassName).append("<iframe></iframe>");
}
```

What I did was splitting the append actions and only `return`-ed the 2nd one.

Your original `iframe` (the one that was there before the js call) most probably got wrapped around with a div called by this new function, because you used `append` to the `body`. In my modified code, I'm appending the `iframe` to the `div` that's got created, so when you apply an attribute, it will be applied to that one only. Again, I'm not 100% sure this is the answer, but for sure my code works.

**[Here is a demo you can fiddle with.](http://jsfiddle.net/js3eM/)**

Comment: Thanks webeno,


Problem is that I may have multiple "myLittleModal"s, so I'm thinking I should have a parameter for an id name as well.

Comment: But the code did work! But I dont know why? And I dont think it will work if I have more than one "myLittleModal" (thus the id factor)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Your code works, but I want to get a handle to the jQuery/DOM object with my little return statement... and then get a handle to it's iframe child... anyone know how? The documentation suggests it can be done, this is how I like to program in C++

return $('body').append("<div...");

Comment: Should i use a variable like this var $myDiv = createModalElement(...)?  in order to get a jquery object, or does it have to be a function like $('body').append( function() { return "div"; }) <-- documentation suggested?